Issue with Sorting French Dates in DataTables
I'm working on a React application using DataTables to display data. I'm using two additional plugins: one for French language support and another for date sorting (ultimate-datetime-sorting). The issue is that date sorting works perfectly in English, but I'm having trouble sorting dates correctly when they are in French.
The dates are not sorting correctly when displayed in French. Everything works fine in English. I tried using moment.js to set the locale to French and a plugin for sorting, but the issue persists.
How can I fix this issue with sorting dates in French? Is there a better approach to handling multilingual date formats and sorting with DataTables and React?
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/fr";

// Function to translate English months to French
export function translateFrenchMonth(dateStr) {
  const translatedMonths = {
    Jan: "Janv",
    Fev: "Févr",
    Mars: "Mars",
    Avr: "Avr",
    Mai: "Mai",
    Juin: "Juin",
    Juil: "Juil",
    Aout: "Août",
    Sept: "Sept",
    Oct: "Oct",
    Nov: "Nov",
    Dec: "Déc",
  };

  const translatedDateStr = dateStr.replace(
    /(Jan|Fev|Mars|Avr|Mai|Juin|Juil|Aout|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec)/g,
    (match) => translatedMonths[match]
  );

  return translatedDateStr;
}

export function updateDateFormat(data) {
  return data?.map((item) => {
    const tm = translateFrenchMonth(item.timestamp);
    const timestamp = item?.timestamp && moment(tm, userTimeFormat);

    return {
      ...item,
      timestamp,
    };
  });
}

const userLanguage = baja.getLanguage();
if (userLanguage === "en") {
  moment.locale("en");
} else {
  moment.locale("fr");
}

const columnDefs = [
  {
    language: userLanguage,
    type: "date",
    targets: 0,
    render: function (data) {
      return moment(data).local().format(userTimeFormat);
    },
  },
];

// Applying translated date format
const dataTable = utils.updateDateFormat(data);

<StyledDataTable
  ...
  data={dataTable}
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
/>


why not use iso dates and convert for display to wanted format?
